# solve_ivp error : Required step size is less than spacing between numbers

Tags: python, math, scipy, ode

I have been trying to implement a model of unstable glacier flow in Python, solving the ODEs in scipy, with the RK45 method.
The original model publication can be found [here](http://https:%20//www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-glaciology/article/general-theory-of-glacier-surges/043253068C3895A0A41D217CD7F92ADD).

Now, I think I understand what is going on with the error but I cannot find a way to fix it.
I don't know if it comes from my implementation or from the ODEs themselves.
I've been through the units several times, checking that all times were in seconds, all distances in meters and so on.
I've tried with different t_eval and even different values of certain constants, but not been able to solve my problem.

I started by creating a class with all constants.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.units as u

SECONDS_PER_YEAR = 3600*24*365.15
class Cst:
    #Glenn's flow Law
    A = 2.4e-25 
    n = 3. 
    
    #Standard physical constants
    g = 10.#*(u.m)*(u.second**-2)
    rho = 916#*(u.kilogram*(u.m**-3)) 
    
    #Thermodynamics
    cp = 2000#**(u.Joule)*(u.kilogram**-1)*(u.Kelvin**-1)
    L = 3.3e5#*(u.Joule)*(u.kilogram**-1) 
    k = 2.1 #*(u.Watt)*(u.m**-1)*'(u.Kelvin**-1)'
    DDF = 0.1/SECONDS_PER_YEAR #*(u.m)*(u.yr**-1)*'(u.Kelvin**-1) 
   
    
    K = 2.3e-47#*((3600*24*365.15)**9)#*((u.kilogram**-5)*(u.m**2)*(u.second**9))
    C = 9.2e13#*((u.Pascal)*(u.Joule)*(u.m**-2))
    
    #Weertman friction law
    q = 1
    p = 1/3
    R = 15.7#*((u.m**(-1/3))*(u.second**(1/3))) 
    
    d = 10#*u.m 
    sin_theta = 0.05
    Tm = 0+273.15 #*u.Kelvin
    T_offset = -10+273.15#*u.Kelvin 
    w = 0.6 #u.m 
    
    Wc = 1000.#*u.m
    
    #Velocities
    u1 = 0/SECONDS_PER_YEAR #m/s
    u2 = 100/SECONDS_PER_YEAR # m/s
 
    #Dimensionless parameters
    alpha = 5.
```

Then I declared the problem-specific parameters specified in the paper:

```
#All values are from Table 1

a0 = 1./SECONDS_PER_YEAR#* m/s (u.meter*((u.second)**-1))
l0 = 10000#*(u.meter)

E0 = 1.8e8#(Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta*a0*(l0**2))/(Cst.L*Cst.K))**(1/Cst.alpha)#*(u.Joule/u.m**2)
T0 = 10#E0/(Cst.rho*Cst.cp*Cst.d)#*u.Kelvin
w0 = 0.6#E0/(Cst.rho*Cst.L)#*u.m
N0 = 0.5#Cst.C/E0#*u.Pascal

H0 = 200 #((Cst.R*(Cst.C**Cst.q)*(a0**Cst.p)*(l0**Cst.p))/(Cst.rho*Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta*(E0**Cst.q)))**(1/(Cst.p+1))
t0 = 200 #H0/a0
u0 =  50/SECONDS_PER_YEAR#((Cst.rho*Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta*(E0**Cst.q)*a0*l0)/(Cst.R*(Cst.C**Cst.q)))**(1/(Cst.p+1))


Q0 = (Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta*a0*(l0**2))/Cst.L
S0 = ((Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta*a0*(l0**2)*Cst.Wc)/(Cst.L*Cst.K*((Cst.rho*Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta)**(1/2))))**(3/4)

lamb = ((2.*Cst.A*(Cst.rho*Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta)**Cst.n)*(H0**(Cst.n+1)))/((Cst.n+2)*u0)
chi = N0/(Cst.rho*Cst.g*H0)


gamma = 0.41
kappa = 0.7
phi = 0.2
delta = 66
mu = 0.2
```

Define the model :

```
def model(t, x):
    #Initial values
    H_hat = x[0]
    E_hat = x[1]
    
    #Thickness
    H = H_hat*H0
    
    #Enthalpy
    E_hat_plus = max(E_hat, 0)
    E_hat_minus = min(E_hat, 0)
    
    E_plus = E_hat_plus*E0
    E_minus = E_hat_minus*E0


    a_hat = 1. 
    theta_hat = Cst.sin_theta/Cst.sin_theta 
    l_hat =l0/l0 
    
    T_a = 0+273.15
    T = -10+273.15
    
    # Equation 3
    m_hat = (Cst.DDF*(T_a-Cst.T_offset))/a0

    S_hat = 0.
    T_a_hat = T_a/T0

    #Equation A7
    if E_plus > 0:
        N = min(H/chi, 1./E_plus)
    else:
        N = H/chi
        
    phi = min(1., E_plus/(H/chi))
    
    #Equation 8
    inv_p = 1./Cst.p
    u = (Cst.rho*Cst.g*Cst.sin_theta/Cst.R * H * (N**(-Cst.q)))**inv_p

    #Equation A7
    beta = min(max(0, (u-Cst.u1)/(Cst.u2-Cst.u1)), 1)

    #Equation A4
    dHdt_hat = (
        a_hat - m_hat
        + 1./l_hat*(
            theta_hat**inv_p
            * H_hat**(1.+inv_p)
            * N**(-Cst.q*inv_p)
            + lamb*(theta_hat**Cst.n)
        )
    )
    
    #Equation A5
    dEdt_hat = 1./mu*(
        theta_hat**(1+inv_p) * H_hat**(1.+inv_p) * N**(-Cst.q*inv_p)
        + gamma
        + kappa*(E_hat_minus - T_a_hat)/H_hat
        - 1./l_hat * (
            theta_hat * E_hat_plus**Cst.alpha 
            + phi * theta_hat**(1./2) * S_hat**(4/3.)
        )
        + delta * beta * m_hat
    )
    return [dHdt_hat, dEdt_hat]
```

And finally call it :

```
tmax = 200*SECONDS_PER_YEAR# *u.years
t = np.linspace(0, tmax, 10000)

sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(model, t_span=[t[0], t[-1]], y0=[1, 1], t_eval=t, method='RK23')
print(sol)
```

Which yields

```
message: 'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.'
     nfev: 539
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
      sol: None
   status: -1
  success: False
        t: array([0.])
 t_events: None
        y: array([[1.],
       [1.]])
 y_events: None
```

Comment: The most common reason for this error is that the system runs away to infinity. Often there is a singularity in the system involved, that is, division-by-zero. You can try to apply a mollified division in changing `x/y` to `x*y/(eps**2+y**2)`. You will have to determine afterwards where the solution deviates from the original equation.